# Structuring a three site Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra

I currently have a 3 nodes cluster in one location (let's call it Main), and I want to add two new locations (let's say remote1 and remote2).

The use case I'm trying to address is some sort of logging, I want remote1 and remote2 to be able to log some data fast and reliably. So I opted for 3 new nodes in each remote location, on which I would persist using `LOCAL_QUORUM`, the data would be then replicated to the Main location where it could be read by another app.

My problem is that if both remote location write in the same Column Family, the replication factor would be `{ 'remote1': 3, 'remote2': 3, 'Main': 1 }` but then data from remote1 would be replicated to remote2 and vice-versa, which I don't want.

One solution would be to have two different Column Families with each a replication factor of `{ 'remoteX': 3, 'Main': 1 }` but I end up with my data split up and less easy to read.

Is there another way to acheive this?

Comment: not clear to me... can you clarify your question little bit so that every one can properly undestand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not a way to have data centers in cassandra with a "hub and spoke" persistence strategy with one keyspace.  If you don't want your data persisted to all the data centers you have to use multiple keyspaces. One with remote1 and main, and another with remote2 and main.